# Infinite Series Summation in terms of variable $r$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Finding $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{2r^2-1}{4r^4+1}$

TRY $4r^4+1=(2r^2-2r+1)(2r^2+2r+1)$ So $\displaystyle\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{2r^2-1}{(2r^2-2r+1)(2r^2-2r+1)}$ but how i convert in Telescopic sum because in numeratoror it has $(2r^2-2)$ instead of $4r$. Thanks

Comment: Is it $2r^2-1$ as in title or $2r^2-2$ as in the body of the question ? The problem is **very** different. Please fix. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\;\;
\displaystyle\frac{2r^2-1}{(2r^2-2r+1)(2r^2+2r+1)} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2r-1}{2r^2-2r+1} - \frac{2r+1}{2r^2+2r+1}\right)
\,$.

Comment: Did you notice that $(2r^2-1)$ became $(2r^2-2)$ ? This makes the problem quite different (in particular for the limit when $n\to \infty$).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks for catching that, fixed now. Not only had I *not* noticed, but I did my draft calculations using the top line $2r^2-1\,$, but when I posted I copy/pasted the LHS MathJax from the next line $2r^2-2\,$, which of course no longer matched my RHS. That should teach me to doublecheck better.

Comment: In fact, I looked at $$f(a)=\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{2r^2-a}{4r^4+1}$$ which is very interesting since the result is $f(a)=\frac{a}{2}-\frac{1}{4} \pi  (a-1) \tanh \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$

Comment: That's neat, indeed, though a **very** different problem, like you said in that other comment. And it enforces the point that something like $\sum \frac{P(n)}{Q(n)Q(n+1)}$ almost never telescopes, unless $P$ was carefully chosen to.

Comment: You are perfectly correct !

Answer (score 2):

*This is too long for a comment.*

In the initial post, there was a "small" typo (namely $(2r^2-1)$ in the title but $(2r^2-2)$ in the body of the question).

This made me considering the more general problem of
$$A_k=\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{2r^2+k}{4r^4+1}$$

What I did was to consider $a,b,c,d$ to be the roots of $4r^4+1=0$ and use partial fraction decomposition leading to 
$$\frac{2r^2+k}{4r^4+1}=\frac \alpha {r-a}+\frac \beta {r-b}+\frac \gamma {r-c}+\frac \delta {r-d}$$ and, using generalized harmonic numbers
$$\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac 1{r-a}=H_{n-a}-H_{-a}$$ Now, considering the asymptotics
$$H_p=\gamma +\log \left({p}\right)+\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$ recombining, simplifying (a lot of tedious work - but I enjoyed), we finally end with the nice 
$$A_k=-\frac{k}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}   (k+1) \tanh \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$$ which shows the specificity of $k=-1$.